# How to recognize slash between two numbers on my images with Tesseract?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have some images with two numbers separated by `/` very close to them. Tesseract doesn't recognize that dash at all, or recognizes it as `1` in most of them (For few images it works).

[image: Input 1]

My Tesseract code:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng',config='--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=/0123456789').strip()
```

I've tried with other `psm` and `oem` configs. I've been playing with the images a lot, e.g. with `cv2.threshold`, `cv2.cvtColor`, resizing.

**EDIT:**

After

```py
img = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]` <br>
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0), fx=1.5, fy=1.5)`
```

most of the images return good values, but some of them add `5` in random place (images after conversion):

[image: Input 2]

[image: Input 3]

and few cases still don't recognize the slash.

Comment: A) can you get higher-resolution image which preferably isn’t jpeg (lossy) format? And b) can you make the image black text on white background?

Comment: A) can't get better resolution
B) I did by `img = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Grayscaling, even more enlarging, and a different threshold did the job on my machine:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


def extract_stats(img_filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(img_filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 4.0, 4.0)
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    config = '--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789/"'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config)
    print(text.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', ''))


for filepath in ['Bzh3j.png', 't9gAh.png', 'BBy2P.png']:
    extract_stats(filepath)
# 4319/6149
# 943/7114
# 103/6149
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
Python:        3.9.6
PyCharm:       2021.2
OpenCV:        4.5.3
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

With tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-20210401 and the tessdata_best I got correct result with this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'bin\\tesseract.exe'
tessdata = "tessdata"

img = cv2.imread('t9gAh.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0), fx=3.0, fy=3.0)
bin_inverted = ~cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
test = pytesseract.image_to_string(bin_inverted, config=f'--psm 6 --tessdata-dir "{tessdata}"')
print(text.replace('\n\f'', ''))
```